# Help with Homework Problem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $f_k(x)=|x-1/k|^{-2/3} (k=1,2,3,...).$ Do the $f_k$ have an integrable majorant, meaning a function bounding $f_k$ that satisfies the dominated convergence theorem, on the interval [0,1] with respect to the Lebesgue measure? Are they uniformly integrable here?

I'm fairly certain that they do have an integrable majorant since the functions themselves are all integrable, I'm just not sure how to show it formally. I'm also not sure if they are uniformly integrable, though I suspect not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, these functions are easy to integrate (just remove the absolute values, then integrate from $1/k$ to $1$ and subtract the integral from $0$ to $1/k$), why not do this and see what happens?

Comment: Integrating the functions gives me that $\int_0^1f_n=3[(1-1/k)^{1/3}-(-1/k)^{1/3}]$. This clearly gives me a value for the integral for every k but what does it say about the existence of an integrable majorant?

Comment: Well, $k$ is an integer, so what can you tell about the absolute values of the two terms on your right hand side?

Comment: Ok, so if I did things right, by looking at the absolute values and letting k go off to infinity gives me an upperbound on the integrals of 3. So they should have an integrable majorant since they are bounded for each k. Is that enough to show that they are uniformly integrable as well?